# How to add line breaks into HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

I'm working on a website that uses a datafeed. Within that datafeed (that comes in via a CSV file) there is a paragraph of text. The client is entering the text in bullet point format and would like it to be displayed as such. For example:

> - First point here... * Second point here... * Third point here...

*(The client is using the asterix for all points, it's the text editor here converting the first into a bullet point)*

Does anyone know a way I'm able to insert line breaks before all but the first asterix so this appears as a list? Maybe with a little javascript?

Ideally the list would appear like this:

> - First point here...
> - Second point here...
> - Third point here...

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: You could just replace the asterisks with an `li` (as they don't need to be closed): `text.replace('*', '<li>');`

Comment: Create a list (an unordered `<ul>`) and make list items (`<li>`) out of all text nodes beginning with asterix. Make the formatting with CSS, you can set different style for the first list element with the selector `li:first-child`.

Comment: shouldn't there be a closing tag for <li > too?

Comment: @user3425760 the closing tag for an `li` is optional: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Pete, how should I insert that into the page, within a script tag I presume? Maybe like this... <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () { text.replace('*', '<li>'); }); </script>

Comment: Can you provide the html of the initial list in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I'm guessing here from a mixture of your question and comments but it looks as if the rendered html of your list would be something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>First point here... * Second point here... * Third point here...</li>
</ul>
```

From your comment, it looks as if you are using jQuery so you can do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        var listItem = $(this),
            text =  listItem.text().replace(/\*/g, '<li>');

        listItem.html(text);
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kkhLoc0z/)

Comment: Thanks @Pete, the html code is: <p class="property_description">* First point here... * Second point here... * Third point here...</p>. I've updated the script to focus on .property_description but do you know if there is a way to get the script to also add in an opening and closing <ul> tags, but only in cases where asterix's are featured?

Comment: @TomPerkins, I would do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/enwwc8q6/ but it relies on the asterisk text being the only text in the paragraph

Comment: that looks perfect, thank you so much. Please let me know if there's anything I can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions your can write:

```
input.replace(/\s\*/g, '\n&bull;');
```

This will replace all * preceeded by space characters by a bullet symbol started from a new line.

If you need to make a real HTML markup out of the input (like li tags), you will have to dig into regexp a little deeper. This [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) page is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answers you already have, you could use a regular expression to replace the asterisks with `<li>`. E.g.:

**HTML**

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var str = ' * one * two * three';
str = str.replace(/\s\*/g, '<li>');
$('#output').html('<ul>'+str+'</ul>');
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uyswq7mx/)